# How to open overlay inside a div in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap to design my page. I am using Modal and want overlay to open in my div instead of body. so I did this

```
$(function () {
    $('.category_more').click(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal();
        $('.modal-backdrop').appendTo('.overlay-background');
        $('body').removeClass();
    });
});
```

where overlay background is my div. My css read like this

```
.modal::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -4px; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
.modal, .modal-backdrop {
    position: absolute !important;
}
.modal.fade.in{
    padding-right:0px !important;
}
.overlay-background{
    position:relative;
}
```

but when I clicked my button, it fade in and fade out quickly and entire body moved to right by 15px.

please help.

Comment: My suggestion (by experience) do not use bootstrap `modal-backdrop` change it's property to `display:none` and `opacity:0` because of these properties `.modal-backdrop {position: fixed;top: 0px;right: 0px;bottom: 0px;left: 0px;z-index: 1040;background-color: #000;}` not possible what you are trying to achieve unless you adjust them or create your own custom backdrop